# Is there a way with Java Generics to take Generic parameter that requires implementation of 2 interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Say I have this code -

```
public interface ParentInterface1 {
    public List<? extends ChildInterface1> getChildren();
    public void setChildren(List<? extends ChildInterface1> children);
}
public interface ParentInterface2 {
    public List<? extends ChildInterface2> getChildren();
    public void setChildren(List<? extends ChildInterface2> children);
}
public interface ChildInterface1 {
    public String getField();
    public void setField(String field);
}
public interface ChildInterface2 {
    public String getField();
    public void setField(String field);
}
public class LParentImpl implements ParentInterface1, ParentInterface2 {
    private List<ChildImpl> list;
    public List<ChildImpl> getChildren() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setChildren(List<... wants to accept ChildImpl, which 
                                   implements ChildInterface1 & ChildInterface2> children) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
public class ChildImpl implements ChildInterface1, ChildInterface2 {
    private String field;
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }
    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the setChildren() in the ParentImpl class work, without removing the Generic typing completely from the interfaces and implementation?

I'd like to do something like -

```
public void setChildren(List<? extends ChildInterface1 & ChildInterface2> children)
```

This sort of interface/implementation structure is valid for non Generic types, but it seems some aspect of the run-time erasure of Generics might make this impossible? Or am I missing some magic syntax?

Edit: Using the List<? extends ChildInterface1 & ChildInterface2> yields this compile error -

```
...\ParentImpl.java:20: > expected
    public void setChildren(List<? extends ChildInterface1 & ChildInterface2> children) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem doesn't makes sense.

`ParentInterface1.setChildren` accepts `List<ChildInterface1>`. Therefore so much `LParentImpl.setChildern`, but you are trying to constrain it so that it does not.

You might want to say, parameterise `ParentInterface1`/`2`, but I'd suggest avoiding multiple inheritance of interface wherever possible (not just where generics are involved).

Comment: You are correct. I was trying to work around the fact you can't satisfy both interfaces with - 
public void setChildren(List<ChildInteface1>)
public void setChildren(List<ChildInteface2>)
because of erasure - but I think what I'm trying to do here isn't possible given the mechanics of the language.

Comment: You can't have both methods overloaded, because of the language spec (overloading is a static issue, so it would be possible despite erasure). The most restrictive parameter type of the method would be something like `List<? extends ChildInterface1 | ChildInterface2>` (not valid Java) which isn't useful. Not sure if you can declare it as just `List<?>`.

Answer (score 11):

You can specify a method that takes an object that implements those two interfaces like this:

```
public <T extends IFirst & ISecond> void doSomething(T obj) {}
```

However, it won't matter much in your example, since both your child interfaces specify the same methods.

Comment: Thank you Jorn!

I stumbled upon this thread when trying to do exactly what your answer gave me (although it doesn't answer the original questioner).

I tried to do this:

 public static interface Displayable
  extends Identifiable, Nameable { }

 public void print(Displayable obj) {
  System.out.println("[" + obj.getIdentity() + "] " + obj.getName());
 }

which doesn't work because the object I am passing doesn't implement Displayable, but not Nameable and Identifiable individually.

Comment: You just prevented me from clicking "Post Your Question". Thanks!.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends ChildInterface1 & ChildInterface2> { ... }
```

Take a look at [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: It's almost valid. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I have to thank Jorn for his answer!

I stumbled upon this thread when trying to do exactly what your answer gave me (although it doesn't answer the original questioner). I tried to do this:

```
public static interface Displayable
    extends Identifiable, Nameable { }

public void print(Displayable obj) {
    System.out.println("[" + obj.getIdentity() + "] " + obj.getName());
}
```

which doesn't work because the object I am passing doesn't implement Displayable, but not Nameable and Identifiable individually.

Using Jorn's technique, I do this:

```
public <T extends Identifiable & Nameable> void print(T obj) {
    System.out.println("[" + obj.getIdentity() + "] " + obj.getName());
}
```

and it works flawless!

I hope this will be helpful to others that having the similar problem as me (and stumbled to this thread).