# Combining bounded wildcards in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

Is there anyway to use a bounded wildcard require a class implement more than one interface?

In otherwords, something like...

```
class Foo<S extends Comparable && Clonable>
```

...which would require that objects extend both interfaces?

I realize I can make another ComparableAndClonable which extends the two but I don't have control over some of the code (So I can't go make my future-S object implement ComparableAndClonable).

Comment: For the record, `S` is a [bounded type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), not a [bounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo<S extends Comparable & Clonable>
```

Should work.

See [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes/745769#745769) for further info.

[1]: