# Java Generics Wildcarding for a single param with multiple class types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method.
It accepts a param, it can either be an object of the `Provider` or `String` class.
Now if I tell that method to accept Object then I can pass it `Provider` or `String` object, but I want to make it type safe using generics and pass only either `Provider` or `String`. How do I do that, is it possible?
I want to achieve something like this:

```
public <T can be String or Provider> void myMethod(T value)
```

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes), but it would not work in my case because none of `Provider` or `String` is an interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not (and can not) use generics for this. Instead simply provide two overloaded method:

```
public void myMethod(String value);
// and
public void myMethod(Provider value);
```

Since both need to have *some* different handling anyway it's actually simpler this way.

Comment: I had thought about the overloading option, but because both would have the same handling in my method, so I was wondering if this can be done via generics. If it cannot be done then I will use overloading now. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @HarshadVyawahare: *how* can you handle `String` and `Provider` in the exact same way? They (probably) don't share any interesting methods. What do you actually *do* with those objects? Can you give an example where you'd handle them the same way?

Comment: from myMethod I am calling another method, which is overloaded to accept either 'Sting' or 'Provider'. That is the only use I make of those 2 objects.

Comment: So you *do* call two different methods (yes, overloaded methods are still distinct methods). You couldn't do that with a single method anyway (or you'd need an ugly `if (value instanceof String)` check). Instead move the common code of the two methods in another (possibly private/protected) method and leave just the call to the other overloaded method in the public method together with the call to the "real code" method.

Comment: I thought if I pass a `String` or a `Provider` to this method then java will decide at runtime which overloaded method to call, and then I do not have to use `instanceof`. Both have roughly the same implementation. I will use overloading as you mentioned.

Comment: @HarshadVyawahare: Java *doesn't* decide this at runtime: the choice between overloaded methods is *always* decided at compile-time. Only *overriden* methods can lead to different code being execute at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Not, that's not possible. How about simply having two overloaded methods instead?

```
public void myMethod(String value)
public void myMethod(Provider value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Ok, if that is not possible via generics then I will use overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly "Provider" or "String"? What do they have in common that makes your method work for both of them? For instance, are both `Comparable`? Then you should use `Comparable` in there. If they do not share something in common, maybe there is a reason that you cannot do what you are trying to do. In that case, just use overloading, as others suggested.

Comment: inflagranti - The thing in common is that they both (either `String` or `Provider`) can be passed as a param to a method I am calling in `myMethod`

Comment: And the implementation of that method that is called is done using overloading I guess?