# How to define a generic parameter which should extend Map or Collection?

Tags: java, generics

I want to defined a generic parameter, which should extend Map or Collection, but I don't know how to do it:

```
public <T> void test(T t) {}
```

I can write it as:

```
public <T extends Map> void test(T t) {}
```

or

```
public <T extends Collection> void test(T t) {}
```

But I don't know is it possible to let T extend Map or Collection in a single method.

Comment: How would you use `t`, if you don't know if it is a `Map` or a `Colleciton`?

Comment: Possible duplication (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes) and as aioobe mentioned it makes your implementation more dirty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

What do you intend to do with the `t` parameter within the method?  Since `Map` and `Collection` have only `Object` as their common supertype, the only methods you can call on `t` will be those on `Object`.  (Even methods on both interfaces, such as `size()`, will be rejected by the compiler.)

With that in mind, is there any reason you can't *overload* the method in this case?  That is, define one implementation for each desired parameter type:

```
public void test(Map<?,?> t) { ... }
public void test(Collection<?> t) { ... }
```

If you don't want to do that for whatever reason, then it seems that you could equally just declare the method to take `Object` and perform a run-time type check of the class.  This is semantically equivalent since you'd have to cast to call `Map` or `Collection`-specific methods anyway, though it does mean that the type check is done at compile time instead of runtime.  Java's type system doesn't let you express this union-type dependency though, so I don't see any other alternative.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible, but you can create two separate methods:

```
public <T extends Map> void test(T t) {
  // do the map part
}

public <T extends Collection> void test(T t) {
  // do the collection part
}
```

If you want to mix them in a handling method you can also write it like this:

```
private void mixedTest(Object t) {
  if (t instanceof Map) {
    // map part
  } else if (t instanceof Collection) {
    // collection part
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown object");
  }
}
```

and call:

```
public <T extends Map> void test(T t) {
  mixedTest(t);
}

public <T extends Collection> void test(T t) {
  mixedTest(t);
}
```

But I'm not sure it will lead to a nice code anyway. I would stick with the first part with the different implementation for the different type of objects.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
public <T extends Map> void test(Map t) {}
```

and

```
public <T extends Collection> void test(Collection t) {}
```

...and then let Java choose the correct one to use?