# Method argument extends class implements interface

Tags: java

I have the following class and interface:

```
public class BasicObject{...}
public interface CodeObject{...}
```

I want to create a method in which the argument needs to be of type BasicObject and implements CodeObject. I tried the following code but it doesn't guarantee clazz to be a class that implements CodeObject.

```
myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject> clazz){...}
```

I want to do something like this but it doesn't compile:

```
myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject implements CodeObject> clazz){...}
```

Comment: This seems to be answering the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Your pattern class has to extend `BasicObject` and extend/implement `CodeObject` (which is actually an interface).  You can do it with multiple classes declared in the wildcard definition of the method signature, like this:

```
public <T extends BasicObject & CodeObject> void myMethod(Class<T> clazz)
```

Note that it won't work if you do it any of these ways:

- `public <T extends BasicObject, CodeObject> void myMethod(Class<T> clazz)`

  This is technically valid syntax, but `CodeObject` is unused; the method will accept any classes that extends `BasicObject`, no matter whether they extend/implement `CodeObject`.
- `public void myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject & CodeObject> clazz)`
  `public void myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject, CodeObject> clazz)`

  These are just wrong syntax according to Java.

Comment: about the part with the  "," , what is the purpose of the "CodeObject"? the class extends from "BasicObject", but what about the "CodeObject" ?

Comment: For me, it works only if I use only T as a parameter type (without Class). Full line:
`public <T extends BasicObject & CodeObject> void myMethod(T clazz)`

Comment: Wow this even works with a constructor! 

Comment: I was confused why `<T extends BasicObject, CodeObject>` "hides type CodeObject" and why it's "technically valid syntax" that seemingly has no purpose until I realized what it's actually doing. You're just defining two seperate types `T` and `CodeObject`, but since there already is a `CodeObject`, you're hiding the first one. It's convention to name generic types with a single capital letter, but you're not actually required to.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an approach which is a bit verbose, but avoids generics headaches. Create another class which does the extending/implementing:

```
public abstract class BasicCodeObject 
    extends BasicObject 
    implements CodeObject {...}
```

Then your method can be:

```
public <T extends BasicCodeObject> void myMethod(Class<T> clazz) {...}
```

Answer (score 10):

There are two approaches to your problem depending on whether you want to pass a **class type** in your method argument that extends `BasicObject` and implements `CodeObject` or a **class object** that does so. There are solutions for both.

**Solution 1:**

If you want to pass the `Class` itself, you can do this, as explained by @bontade,

```
public <R extends BasicObject & CodeObject> void myMethod(Class<R> clazz)
```

and if you want to pass `class` object, you can write

```
public <R extends BasicObject & CodeObject> void myMethod(R clazz)
```

The above is the more complex way which deals with generics.

**Solution 2:**

The following is the simpler one. You can define an abstract class which extends the class you want to extend and implement it:

```
public abstract class TargetClassType extends BasicObject implements CodeObject {

}
```

now if you want to pass the Class itself, do

```
public void myMethod(Class<TargetClassType> clazz)
```

or if you want to pass the class object, write

```
public void myMethod(TargetClassType clazz)
```

Either of the above solutions fits your question, but the second one is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If not all BasicObjects implement CodeObject, then you can use an instanceof / Class.isInstance() check in your method (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```
myMethod(Class<? extends BasicObject> clazz)
{
    if (!clazz.isInstance(CodeObject))
    {
        (indicate that the call was incorrect)
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes but i don't want to do that. Of course any method could use myMethod(Object obj) and then use 'obj.isInstance(...)' but that's what im trying to avoid. I really want the users of my method to be forced to pass a good parameter.