# abstract function, parameter type extends class

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-method

I am building a library management application in Java.

I have an abstract class called `Material`. It has an abstract method called `equals`.

There is a subclass called `Newspaper` and it of course implements `equals`, with the exact same signature as `equals` has inside `Material`:

```
public <T extends Material> boolean equals(Class<T> elementoAComparar) {
    if (this.getTitulo().equals(elementoAComparar.getTitulo()) && this.getFechaPublicacion().equals(elementoAComparar.getFechaPublicacion())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Java cannot resolve any of the methods of `elementoAComparar`. They all exist in `Newspaper` which does extend `Material`.

I got some help [on this thread of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641584/method-argument-extends-class-implements-interface) but I cannot make it really work.

I guess what I don't really get is how to use methods of a class which is working as a generic parameter.

I am sure this is really not that hard, but I have really little experience with Java, please don't be too hard on me :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does your `equals` method take a class as its argument?

Comment: it proves I wasn't understanding what I was doing.

Now I actually understand what I am doing, but still don't understand what I did. I don't really get the meaning of "Class<T>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ajit George mentioned, if you are trying to implement an equality method, then there are cleaner ways of doing it. However, if you simply want your code to compile and run, then you'll need to change the signature of your method. Java cannot resolve of the methods of `elementoAComparar` because `Class` does not have those methods, `Material` does.

You'll need to change your `equals` method signature from

```
public <T extends Material> boolean equals(Class<T> elementoAComparar)
```

to

```
public <T extends Material> boolean equals(T elementoAComparar)
```

The first signature tells the Java that you will be passing an instance of a `Class` object. The second tells Java that you will be passing an instance of an object which is a `Material`.

Comment: I got it. I changed the signature as you told me and casted Material to Periodico (newspaper in Spanish) so I actually have access to all its methods (getFechaPublicacion is not in Material).

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- `Class` objects represent the object class, and `equals` is typically used to compare instances.  Your `equals` declaration implies you want to compare this object with a class object.
- `equals` is defined on `java.lang.Object`, which all objects inherit.  In order for your comparison implementation to work with Java library code, you need to override `Object.equals`.  `equals` predates generics in Java, so `Object.equals` does not use them.  Your implementation needs to check the instance being compared and cast it to your object type in order to get at the fields of the other object.

The answer at [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) provides a good summary and demonstration.

Comment: You are right, I also needed to cast it to my object, otherwise I don't have access to all methods. Thank you.