# Is there any way of imitating OR in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

EDIT: I changed a bit the example for getting the idea:

Like

```
 <Integer or Float>
```

...without having to create a common interface and make a subclass for Integer and Float to implement it

If not, something like this would maybe have more sense and be useful

```
 <E extends Number> <E = (Integer|Float)>
```

If ? is a wildcard why should not we allowed to restrict certain types?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: They seem like chalk and cheese.  The requirement makes no sense to me at all.  Are Strings mathematical entities like Numbers, closed over certain operations?  I thought not.

Comment: Precisely because String is final, an or solution would be needed even more, because we could not solve it with the alternative I propose

Comment: I think it sounds like you need a real object instead of collection.  There's some encapsulation missing here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In very extreme cases (pre-Java 7 without [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)), I would have liked to be able to do that, too. E.g.

```
<E extends Connection or Statement or ResultSet>
```

That would've allowed me to call `E.close()`, no matter what the actual type was. In other words, `E` would contain the "API intersection" of all supplied types. In this case it would contain `close()`, and all methods from [`java.sql.Wrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html) and [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

But unfortunately, you cannot do that. Instead, use method overloading, e.g.

```
void close(Connection c);
void close(Statement s);
void close(ResultSet r);
```

Or plain old `instanceof`

```
if (obj instanceof Connection) {
    ((Connection) obj).close();
}
else if (obj instanceof Statement) { //...
```

Or fix your design, as you probably shouldn't have to intersect APIs of arbitrary types anyway

Comment: In Java 7 all these classes implement [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) so `<E extends AutoCloseable>` is now enough.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I know. It's just an illustration. @GriffeyDog: See Tomasz' answer. JDBC types extend `AutoCloseable`, not `Closeable` (which also extends `AutoCloseable`)

Comment: Another similar case swhere it would be useful is Number interface, DOuble, Integer ... have valueOf but Number, the super, does not. Also: when you need T = concrete subtypes but not the super-OR is handy

Answer (score 16):

It's not possible and I hardly see any value in it. You use generics to restrict type, e.g. in collections. With `or` operator you know as much about the type as much you know about the most specific supertype of both of them, `Object` in this case. So why not just use `Object`?

Hypothetical:

```
List<E extends String or Number> list = //...
```

What is the type of `list.get(0)`? Is it `String` *or* `Number`? But you cannot have a variable of such type. It cannot be `String`, it cannot be `Number` - it can only be... `Object`.

UPDATE: Since you changed your example in question to:

```
<Integer or Float>
```

why won't you just say:

```
<Number>
```

? Note that [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) has methods that allow you to easily extract `floatValue()` and `intValue()`. Do you really need the exact type?

---

Note that you **can** use `and` operator:

```
<E extends Serializable & Closeable>
```

And that makes perfect sense - you can use variable of type `E` where either `Serializable` or `Closeable` is needed. In other words `E` must extend both `Serializable` and `Closeable`. See also: [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756).

Comment: Ok for list is stupid, but for other uses it could be not like this. Even that you could have a String a = list.get(0) or either a Integer a= list.get(0), ugly but not impossible or impracticle. It could throw a CastExeption if error

Comment: @user1352530: avoiding `ClassCastException` and compile time type checking was one of the reasons to include generics in the first place.

Comment: I updated the question with a new approah  which makes the same for me

Comment: @User1352530: I feel OR is always confusing and error prone. May be time to re-architect requirement? Specially in Java with casting, I try to avoid OR as much as possible. As Tomasz said in answer AND is supported.

Comment: `I hardly see any value in it` I want to overload a method, and have version of `flatMap(Function1<T, Try<NewT>> mapper)` and `flatMap(Function1<T, MyCustomCallableThatIsSimilarToTry<NewT>> mapper)`, but I cannot do it as I get error that their both erasure is the same. When I was searching for OR in generics, I hoped I could use it to ducktape fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a real use for it... But anyways, I believe the closest you'd get to it is extending common interfaces for the possible implementations.