# Restrict method to RandomAccess List

Tags: java, list, random-access

I've a method that operates on a `List`, removing certain duplicates. The algorithm is only efficient on lists implementing [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html). To prevent misuse and disappointing performance, I'm wondering how to enforce the `RandomAccess` restriction. The `RandomAccess` interface does not extend `List` unfortunately, so I sort of need to make the variable be two types at once.

I could declare the method to accept `ArrayList` rather than `List`, but other list types can implement `RandomAccess` too (for example, the lists returned by `Collections.synchronizedList` and `Collections.checkedList`), and I don't want to block those.

I tried generics, but couldn't construct a working syntax:

```
public <T> void process(<List<T> extends RandomAccess> list) {
    ...
}
```

I could do:

```
if (!(list instanceof RandomAccess))
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("RandomAccess list required");
```

But then the restriction is only enforced at run time, which is less robust.

Help?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/745756/484441

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use multiple bounds, indicated by an ampersand (`&`):

```
public <T,L extends List<T> & RandomAccess> void process(L  list)
```

Putting it into a (non-compilable, unless you remove the second call) class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    throws Exception
    {
        Main x = new Main();
        x.process(new ArrayList<String>());
        x.process(new LinkedList<String>());
    }

    public <T,L extends List<T> & RandomAccess> void process(L  list) {

    }
}
```

Comment: To don't have 2 parameters: public static <T extends RandomAccess&List<?>> void process(T list){

Comment: @agad - I'm not sure what you're asking. Your example does not apply a bound on the list elements, which is usually important.

Comment: I'm not asking, I'm saying, that parametrization by T is not needed; it is enought to parameterize the method with one parameter for simplicity; it doesn't matter, what elements the list contains, it is important, that the argument is random access list.

Comment: Thanks, that's clever. I didn't know that was possible. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite do what I want. It works for `ArrayList`, `Vector`, `Stack`, and so on, but it rejects `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>())`, because although the returned list implements RandomAccess, that isn't specified in the `synchronizedList` method's return type. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @Boann - No solution. If you don't have compile-time type information, generics can't help you.

Comment: I figured. So this is the right answer to the question I asked, but it's still not something I should do. I'll have to use the run-time `instanceof` test instead.