# Java Generics Comparator

Tags: java, generics

I am coding with Java Generics. I want to define a Binary Tree class generically that will be able to take in any class , and guarantee that that class has the Comparator method compare(T o1, T o2) to see whether I need to follow the right or left subtree for insert into my binary tree.

```
public class treeDB <T implements Comparator> {
    //define my binary tree methods
}
```

That is my best estimation of how to force  to implement Comparator method, but the compile throws an error and I don't know enough to know what it wants.

Comment: I will also suggest a rename: TreeDB. According to Java conventions, class names should be in CamelCase.

Comment: Side note: Take a look [[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes/745769#745769)] if you would like `T` to implement few interfaces and maybe extend some class.

Comment: You almost certainly want `Comparable`, and _not_ `Comparator`.

Comment: What makes you say that? I don't really know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
class treeDB <T extends Comparator<T>> {
...
```

Comment: it makes very little sense for a type to be a *comparator* of itself

Answer (score 3):

Everyone has provided the correct syntax, but you might want to consider using `Comparable` as in

```
class treeDB <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

The differences are subtle, and maybe it isn't the better choice. But it never hurts to look.

Comment: I also think that it is more reasonable to have `T` being `Comparable`, instead making `T` a `Comparator` of `T` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `implements` should be replaced with `extends`. In generics `extends` is the keyword which is used even if the generic type implements an interface.

And secondly, using only `Comparator` will result in a warning it being a raw type. You must parameterize it. This is your solution:

```
public class treeDB <T extends Comparator<T>> {

}
```

Comment: it makes very little sense for a type to be a *comparator* of itself

Comment: @newacct Why not? For a trivial case, what if someone wants to order a couple of objects of same type by putting them in a TreeSet?

Comment: @NishantShreshth: and that type also serves as a comparator of that type?

Comment: @newacct I totally missed that (subtle) thing. It still took me to write a small snippet to believe it.. :-) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I got confused between `Comparator` and `Comparable`. Also, during an add operation such a type will be rejected by TreeSet (type not *comparable*).

Answer (score 1):

This should be `public class treeDB <T extends Comparator>`, not `public class treeDB <T implements Comparator>`.