# Java Multiple boundaries

Tags: java, generics, boundary

what i'm trying to do is as follows:
assume that `getClassFromString()` and `getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass()` already exist.

why can't i use `Class<T extends Named & HasId>`.

i tried generifying the class itself, but can't use stuff like `T.class` etc.

```
public interface Named   {    String getDisplayName(); }
public interface HasId   {    String getId();          }


public class Foo {

public List<PairItem>  getPairItems(String typeId) {

    Class<T extends Named & HasId> clazz = getClassFromString(typeId);

    List<T> allObjects = getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass(clazz);

    List<PairItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (clazz obj : allObjects) {
        items.add(obj.getDisplayName(),ibj.getId());
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need two interfaces? Can't you just have one interface `HasNameAndId` with two methods `getDisplayName()` and `getId()`? What really confuses me about your code is that you seem to be trying to call the two interface methods on a `Class` object. You can't do that. You can only call those methods on instances of those interfaces.

Comment: @pbabcdefp - can't use them as one interface.
it was a mistake, of course - the List is of type T and not clazz.

Comment: Ok, well you can create a third interface `public interface HasNameAndId extends Named, HasId {}`, and then you can have a `List<HasNameAndId>`.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes is interesting to you

Comment: @TheConstructor ive seen this before, but couldn't find a way to make any use of it. i can't generify Foo since i instantiate it with a string. besides, i cant pass T.class as parameter to `getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass()` as well

Comment: You can just add `<T extends Named & HasId>` to `getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass()` and have it return `List<T>` from `Class<T>` that is the way to pass type-parameters around.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you `Foo`-class in this way:

```
public class Foo {

    public <T extends Named & HasId> List<PairItem> getPairItems(String typeId) {
        Class<?> classFromString = getClassFromString(typeId);
        // Java 8 seems to be unable to chain asSubclass-calls. These are merely to verify our unchecked cast
        classFromString.asSubclass(Named.class);
        classFromString.asSubclass(HasId.class);
        //noinspection unchecked
        return getPairItems((Class<T>) classFromString);
    }

    public <T extends Named & HasId> List<PairItem> getPairItems(final Class<T> clazz) {

        List<T> allObjects = getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass(clazz);

        List<PairItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T obj : allObjects) {
            items.add(new PairItem(obj.getDisplayName(), obj.getId()));
        }

        return items;
    }

}
```

This fixes your problems with multiple boundaries as they are only allowed for type-parameters per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).; also I guess that

> If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first.

leads to the problem that the `asSubclass()`-calls can not be chained, otherwise we could remove our unchecked cast.

The second method can profit from the streaming-API like this:

```
    public <T extends Named & HasId> List<PairItem> getPairItems(final Class<T> clazz) {
        List<T> allObjects = getAllObjectsFromRepositoryByClass(clazz);

        return allObjects.stream()
                         .map(obj -> new PairItem(obj.getDisplayName(), obj.getId()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Overall I assumed that you wanted to instantiate `PairItem` and split the method so there is a unchecked and a fully-checked part.