# Java parametrized more then one class.

Tags: java

So, i have one stupid question, but i want to know the answer).
I have a parameterized method:

```
public <E,T extends Enum<T> & ParametrizedCloneable<E>> E getE(Class<T> eClass){...}
```

And perhaps I want to have a list or annotation with classes which i can use in this method.

```
 List<? extends Enum & ParametrizedCloneable> - incorrect
 List<? extends Enum ,ParametrizedCloneable> - incorrect too
```

What the right way?

Comment: I had never even heard of parameterized methods. But what does the `&` do? It extends boths interfaces?

Comment: @popovitsj take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)

Comment: Thx @Turing85, so my assumption was correct. Of course they can't use the comma for this, because it would be ambiguous.