# super and extends combined for generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Can you specify `super` and `extends` for generics in Java?

For example, let's say you have this class structure:
[image: class inheritance structure]

But only want to select classes that: `extends A` and `super ABB`. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent sub-classes of ABB?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to prevent sub-classes of A

Comment: @Marcono1234 Why do you want to prevent subclasses of A? (You can do this by making A `final`)

Comment: @DarthAndroid I rather want for example an ArrayList to contain only objects that `extends A` and `super AAB`, the class `ABB` can still have subclasses, however they should be not allowed for the ArrayList

Comment: Isn't `AB ` a subclass of `A`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes it is, but `super ABB` means that I want subclasses of `ABB` doesn't it? Or why are you asking if I want to prevent subclasses of ABB?

Comment: You could create a dummy interface that you use for the classes you want to have in the arraylist and just have the classes you want implement the dummy interface...http://stackoverflow.com/a/745769/4028085

Comment: `ArrayList<? extends mydummyinterface>` Use the interface as an identifier to identify what classes your object can `extend`...`AB implements mydummyinterface`.

Comment: `super T` means `T` or a super class. not sub-classes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes sorry I mixed it up in that comment but I meant what you said. Because then I don't understand your question "Why do you want to prevent sub-classes of ABB? "

Comment: @Marcono1234 You have stated that you want `super ABB` which means you don't want sub classes of ABB.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, yes you are right. Sorry for the confusion I mixed it up there again. I don't necessarily want to prevent subclasses of ABB but instead only want to make sure that only this inheritance line of classes is allowed, but not for example objects of the class AA.

Comment: In this case you just need `extends ABB`

Comment: @PeterLawrey but I want to allow classes that `extends A`. I just want the line from A to ABB

Comment: Which means you do want to exclude subclasses of ABB or is you want to exclude AA and ABA

Comment: @PeterLawrey The latter one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Java does not let you simultaneously specify both bounds. That said, I've never run across a situation where both bounds were needed. There's almost no reason to include some subclasses but not others - if you need to exclude subclasses, those subclasses are probably violating their contract.

Comment: Try to add, to a restricted collection, a new one restricted element (you need both: super and extends restrictions).