# Generic which is required to implement two interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I have several interfaces like

```
interface CanFly{ .. }
interface CanRun{ .. }
```

and a lot of implementations (done by others)

```
class Dog implements CanFly{ .. }
class Duck implements CanFly, CanRun{ .. }
```

Now at some point I need to use a generic which requires types that implement two interfaces.

```
 class FlyAndRunHandler <ANIMAL extends CanFly AND CanRun>{
    void performAction(ANIMAL animal){
       animal.fly();
       animal.run();
    }
 }
```

In Scala it would look like `ANIMAL extends CanFly with CanRun`. Is there a way to archive this in Java. If required I could write additional interfaces but there is no way to add them to the animal classes.

Comment: could be this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Multiple Bounds` like `<T extends CanFly & CanRun>`

Note: in future if you want to add a class along with `CanFly & CanRun` then make sure to put the class at the beginning like `<T extends className & CanFly & CanRun>` otherwise it will raise an exception