# Java generics issue, modify constraint?

Tags: java, generics

I have two methods:

```
   public <T extends Component> void addComponent(BluePrint bluePrint, Class<T> type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        AddComponent addComponent = addComponentMap.get(type);
        if (addComponent == null) {
            addScriptable(bluePrint, type); <--- fails here
        }
    }
```

if `addComponentMap.get(type);` returns null, i know implicitely that T is of type Scriptabe and need to call:

```
    private <T extends Scriptable> void addScriptable(BluePrint bluePrint, Class<T> type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        scriptableSystems.add(new ScriptableSystem<T>());
    }
```

The issue is that the upper bound for T in the second method is Scriptable and in the first method its Component, therefore type "could" potentially be any component when addComponent is null.

Can i somehow narrow the constraint to Scritpable when addComponent is null? Or somehow explicitly say that when addComponent is null T will extend Scriptable, before calling addScriptable?

Worth mentioning perhaps is that Scriptable inherits from component.

Comment: Are the other components in the map also `Scriptable`? In that case, make `T extends Scriptable` in the first one, too. Otherwise, *you could just cast if you definitely know*. If you cannot guarantee that all components in the map are `Scriptable`, I'd say you are out of luck using only generics.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes).

Comment: @MalteHartwig The other components in the map are not Scriptable. How do i cast the variable type? What other methods could i use?

Comment: @Tagor, I wrote an answer explaining how `Class.isAssignableFrom()` could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot narrow down the generic type of class in your map, you can still cast. And to be safer, you can use `Class.isAssigneableFrom`, which is an instanceof for classes (instead of objects):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Class<? extends Number>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Class<? extends Number> someNumberClass = map.get("Double");
    if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(someNumberClass)) {
        acceptInteger((Class<Integer>) someNumberClass);
    }
}

public static void acceptInteger(Class<Integer> c) { }
```

This doesn't even need the null check and could work for cases where `addComponent` is not null. In your example, you would do:

```
if (Scriptable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) { // add the null check if necessary
   addScriptable(bluePrint, (Class<Scriptable>) type);
}
```

Comment: @Tagor For a more detailed explanation, please read [John Bollinger's extensive answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46773600/7653073).

Comment: Nice! never heard of `isAssigneableFrom`, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the upper bound for T in the second method is
>   Scriptable and in the first method its Component, therefore type
>   "could" potentially be any component when addComponent is null.

That's about right, but I'd put it more strongly: since `Scriptable` extends `Component` (as opposed to the other way around), type argument `T` in method `addComponent()` can *always* be a type that is not bounded above by Scriptable.

> Can i somehow narrow the constraint to Scritpable when addComponent is
>   null?

Sure.  Supposing that you don't want a tighter bound in other cases, that's what casting is for:

```
public <T extends Component> void addComponent(BluePrint bluePrint, Class<T> type)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    AddComponent addComponent = addComponentMap.get(type);

    if (addComponent == null) {
        addScriptable(bluePrint, (Class<? extends Scriptable>) type);
    }
}
```

You will of course get a compiler warning about the cast.  This is right and proper because that code depends on a condition that the compiler cannot verify.

> Or somehow explicitly say that when addComponent is null T will
>   extend Scriptable, before calling addScriptable?

That's exactly what you *do* say by casting.  A cast of a value of reference type is effectively an assertion that you know more about the runtime type of that value than the compiler can prove.

Additionally, you can perform a runtime test if you'd rather have a filaure behavior different from a `ClassCastException`:

```
if (!Scriptable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
    throw new MyChosenException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very detailed answer indeed.