# Java generics with multiple enums implementing an interface

Tags: java, generics, enums

I want to pass a list of enum classes to a method, where all of the enums implement a common interface, and have the method return one of the enum values.

Looking at [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes), it seems that

```
public class Main
{
    interface Foo {}

    enum First implements Foo {
        A, B, C;
    }

    enum Second implements Foo {
        X, Y, Z;
    }

    interface Bar {}

    enum Third implements Bar {
        M, N, P;
    }
    enum Fourth implements Bar {
        A, X, Z;
    }


    public static <I, T extends Enum<?> & I> 
      I enumVarArgs(Class<? extends T>... classes) 
    {
        // Do stuff and return some instance of T
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = enumVarArgs(First.class,
                              Second.class);
        Bar bar = enumVarArgs(Third.class,
                              Fourth.class);
    }
}
```

should do what I want.  However, this fails to compile under Java 10:

```
[ERROR] /me/test/src/main/java/test/Main.java:[17,42] error: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter I
  where I,T are type-variables:
    I extends Object declared in method <I,T>enumVarArgs(Class<? extends T>...)
    T extends Enum<?>,I declared in method <I,T>enumVarArgs(Class<? extends T>...)
[INFO] 1 error
```

From the error message, I am guessing that Java wants me to do something like `T extends Enum<?> & Serializable`, where I pass an actual interface, rather than a type parameter.  However, I need the API to be general so that `I` remains a generic parameter.

Is there a syntax that makes this work?

If it matters, we are using Java 10.

Comment: are you aware that your A's and X's will be different? i.e. First.a!=Fourth.a

Answer (score 0):

If interfaces are your design, then you can make the two interfaces extend a marker interface:

```
interface FooBar{}

interface Foo extends FooBar {}

interface Bar extends FooBar {}
```

And you can use this marker interface:

```
public static <T extends Enum<?> & FooBar> 
      FooBar enumVarArgs(Class<? extends T>... classes) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Declaring `I extends FooBar` and returns an `I` means you need an unchecked cast from `FooBar` to `I` in this method

Comment: @yyyy That's absolutely right. I didn't catch that surely because I didn't have to implement the method. Thanks, I've removed the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
interface OnlyImpelents<T> {}
interface Foo extends OnlyImpelents<Foo> {}
interface Bar extends OnlyImpelents<Bar> {}

static <T extends Enum<?> & OnlyImpelents<? super T>> T enumVarArgs(T... values) {
    return values[0];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = enumVarArgs(First.A, Second.X);
}
```

The marker interface `OnlyImpelents<T>` prevents any class from implementing both `Foo` and `Bar`

The only way to get enum values from a enum class is via reflection, which doesn't need to have a static type. Personally I think this is not a good object-oriented design, using `T...` as args should be better