# Bound parameter type to one of multiple candidates

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a method in Java that takes in a generic type:

```
public <K> void doSomething(List<K> inputList, Function<DB, Map<String, K>> func);
```

`K` is only allowed to to extend either one class or another (`A` or `B`)

How can I define that in Java?

Comment: Make an interface that does nothing....and have both A and B implement it.... then extend K on that empty interface

Comment: I'm not allowed to change `A` and `B` as they are import legacy classes deeply integrated to the system.

Comment: then your best bet is to create two different `doSomething` methods... one for A... and one for B

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can't. You can extend only one class (should be first), and interface.
Please take a look on answer:
[Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)