# Is there a way for this interface to have one more default implementation?

Tags: java, types

In this interface, I have default implementations:

```
public interface Arithmeticable<T extends AlgebraicInteger> {
    
    T plus(T addend);
    
    T plus(int addend);
    
    default T negate() {
        return this.times(-1);
    }
    
    T minus(T subtrahend);
    
    default T minus(int subtrahend) {
        return this.plus(-subtrahend);
    }
    
    T times(T multiplicand);
    
    T times(int multiplicand);
    
    T divides(T divisor) throws NotDivisibleException;
    // may also throw a runtime exception for division by 0
    
    T divides(int divisor) throws NotDivisibleException;
    // may also throw a runtime exception for division by 0
    
}
```

Naturally, one would think there is one more default implementation to be had here:

```
    default T minus(T subtrahend) {
        return this.plus(subtrahend.negate());
    }
```

But the problem is that the compiler doesn't know `negate()` can be called on `subtrahend`. In fact it's a human assumption that `T` implements `Arithmeticable<T>`. It could just as easily be implemented by a class other than `T`.

The only thing we can count on `T` to have is what `Object` and `AlgebraicInteger` define. Is there a way to require `T` to implement `Arithmeticable<T>`?

I have this vague memory of doing something like this in Scala. Can it be done in Java?

Comment: How did you define `AlgebraicInteger`? Can that interface include the `negate` method?

Comment: What is the difference between `AlgebraicInteger` and `Arithmeticable`, why are these two separate types?

Comment: @Thilo Like this: https://github.com/Alonso-del-Arte/algebraic-integer-calculator/blob/master/code-source/algebraics/AlgebraicInteger.java Yes, `AlgebraicInteger` could include `Arithmeticable`. It wouldn't be terribly SOLID, but it would be a valid answer to this question.

Comment: For your last question, you can say `<T extends AlgebraicInteger & Arithmeticable<T>>` https://stackoverflow.com/q/745756/14955

Comment: @Thilo "why are these two separate types?" Honestly, it's mostly because I haven't figured out arithmetic beyond the quadratics.